# Robot framework input text after tab

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

Im making a automated test but the input fields doesn't have any specific id and classes. I don't want to select everything by using xpath so i thought i was going to use the `Press Keys` function. After i put the text in the first input i do the function:

`Press Keys  LOCATOR   TAB`

After that i used the tab button, it goes to the next form but how do input text in the form?
I know there is the `input text` function but it needs the locator for entering text. How can i input text without using the `input text locator` ?

Comment: In that case you would have to use `Press Keys` for pretty much every input. Try to use `Input Text` if it's possible in any way. If possible, ask the developer to add `id`s and `class`es or similar. Or try to find some other unique identifiers. HTML code of the related elements would help to give you the best approach.

Comment: _"I don't want to select everything by using xpath"_ - why?

Comment: @bryanOakley Because using xpath isn't in my opinon future proof, when the developers change the layout of the websites or even add one form the whole xpath is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to still take the xpath even if it has no specific id or class, it also works with an xpath like this: // html / body / table / tbody / tr [4] / td / center / form / table / tbody / tr [ 4] / td.

Example Input Text:
Input Text [locator, text, clear = True].

Example Press Keys:
Press Keys, locator, ALT

Comment: I tried avoiding xpath for future proof reasons, do you think selecting/ entering text through javascript is a better solution?

Comment: It Depends by what you want to do: if the position of your text doesn't matter for passing test, javascript could be a valid alternative, but in my opinion full xpath is a better solution to test both situations: place and text.